# Inheritance fails

Tags: inheritance, extjs, window

im develop windows decorators for forms and grids. I have an abstract class:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.ui.DecoratorAbstract',{
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.decoratorAbstract',
    initComponent: function(){
        this.resizable = this.cfg[0];
        this.closable = this.cfg[1];
        this.minimizable = this.cfg[2];
        //this.items = this.anItem;   
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }  
});
```

One subclass, without buttons to contains a grid, this works fine:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.ui.DecoratorGrid',{
    extend: 'AM.view.ui.DecoratorAbstract',
    alias: 'widget.decoratorGrid',
    initComponent: function(){
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

And last, for forms, with two buttons:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.ui.DecoratorForm',{
    extend: 'AM.view.ui.DecoratorAbstract',
    alias: 'widget.decoratorForm',
    initComponent: function(){
        this.buttons = [
            { text:'Guardar', action:'save', iconCls: 'ico-save' },
            { text:'Cancelar', action:'cancel', iconCls: 'ico-cancel' }
        ];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

The problem is, that te buttons displayed arent guardar/cancelar. The windows shows buttons of the main toolbar program.

An image:
[image]

Any ideas ?.

Note: The Toolbar is create in app.js. The Windows, are test in Firebug:

```
Ext.create('AM.view.ui.DecoratorForm',{cfg:[true,true,true]}).show();
```

Comment: What do you mean "shows buttons of the main toolbar program"?

Comment: @kevhender now post an image.

Comment: Can you show where you're instantiating these classes?  You must have something configured wrong somewhere...